# Change object property of an object inside an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuex

actually I have done it already but I'm sure that you can do it with ES6.

Doesn't matter your logic, the goal is to find some object inside nested arrays and change the data(change the property object) :

```
let selectedItem = { LinkID: 1 }; // item to be changed inside my vuex store

//sindecs is a property inside my vuex store

let sindecs = [
  {
    estado: { id: 2, siga: "AL", nome: "Alagoas" },
    uf: { id: 2, nome: "SP" },
    link: [
      { LinkID: 1, Link: "link1", Active: false },
      { LinkID: 2, Link: "link 2", Active: false }
    ],
    SindecID: 3
  },
  {
    estado: { id: 19, siga: "RJ", nome: "Rio de Janeiro" },
    uf: { id: 1, nome: "RJ" },
    link: [{ LinkID: 3, Link: "rio", Active: false }],
    SindecID: 4
  }
];



//this is the for inside my mutations, I want to change here to a easier way to change the value.
for (let i = 0; i < sindecs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < sindecs[i].link.length; j++) {
    if (sindecs[i].link[j].LinkID === selectedItem.LinkID) {
      sindecs[i].link[j].Active = !sindecs[i].link[j].Active;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: By easier way you mean without 2 loops?

Comment: Yes bro, the smarter way.. imagine if I have 3 nested arrays? It would be a hell hahaha....

Comment: Well from a performance standpoint, you can't do much without changing your state's data structure.

Comment: I did not get you...

Comment: So in your `sindecs`, you have to do `sindecs[0].link[0].LinkID`.
So you need move the identifier up two levels, so that you can directly do `sindecs[0].LinkID`. 
But then LinkID is not unique, so you have to do some manipulations so that the identifier is always unique.

Have a look at this https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr
Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar in `ES6`. It is just `clean syntax`.

```
const toggleState = (sindecs, id) => {
  sindecs.forEach((sinde) => {
    const link = sinde.link.find((s) => s.LinkID === id);
    if (link) link.Active = !link.Active;
  });
};
toggleState(sindecs, selectedItem.LinkID)
```

Same as above, but `good in performance`. If there is only `one match`, this will not `iterate` all data. This will `break loop`.

```
const toggleState = (sindecs, id) => {
  let link;
  sindecs.some((sinde) => {
    link = sinde.link.find((s) => s.LinkID === id);
    return Boolean(link);
  });
  if (link) link.Active = !link.Active;
};
toggleState(sindecs, selectedItem.LinkID);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const toggleState = (sindecs, id) => {
  let link;
  sindecs.some((sinde) => {
    link = sinde.link.find((s) => s.LinkID === id);
    return Boolean(link);
  });
  if (link) link.Active = !link.Active;
};

let selectedItem = { LinkID: 1 }; 
let sindecs = [{"estado":{"id":2,"siga":"AL","nome":"Alagoas"},"uf":{"id":2,"nome":"SP"},"link":[{"LinkID":1,"Link":"link1","Active":false},{"LinkID":2,"Link":"link 2","Active":false}],"SindecID":3},{"estado":{"id":19,"siga":"RJ","nome":"Rio de Janeiro"},"uf":{"id":1,"nome":"RJ"},"link":[{"LinkID":3,"Link":"rio","Active":false}],"SindecID":4}];
toggleState(sindecs, selectedItem.LinkID);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sindecs, null, 2)) // update..
```

Comment: Dude, I got you totally, It's right but I don't how to attach this end link object to the sindec, could you be more easier for me?

Comment: I didnt get you. Do you me sample. i have added one.

Comment: It's interesting even you changing the link.Active without reference the state it will change the sindecs array object. It's works, many thanks !